# SQL delete every second row

Tags: mysql, sql

So i have an error in my database where the table did duplicated itselfe into it and has no longer a distinct value in each row and thus each row is 100% duplicated.
Now i need to delete every second row to fix that issue, but exporting, deleting those rows and importing it back in, runs into an error.
My next idea is to run a DELETE function that deletes every second row.
My current approach doesn't seem to work.

```
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num_row
    FROM `category`
    WHERE num_row=2
    ORDER BY `auto_increment` ASC
```

This is my table:
[image]

Comment: try num_row % 2 == 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can find a workaround with a tmp table.

```
CREATE TABLE tmp SELECT distinct * FROM category;
```

Then empty your table category and Insert all the data from tmp table in it.
If you have any forein_key problem just disable it while you're cleaning your duplicated lines :

```
SET foreign_key_checks=0;
```

And when you're done

```
SET foreign_key_checks=1;
```

Comment: It worked just like i wanted, thanks a lot.
If i understand it right, this removes all duplications inside a table right?
Or might some data get lost nontheless?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what it does. The "distinct" instruction guaranty you won't have any duplication in the select result. So when you create a table using "select disinct * ", the table created contains no duplications. You won't lose any data here

Comment: Is there a way i can do that with all tables at once and create them with tmp as prefix?
Seems like more then 30 tables have that problem and picking them manually and create a tmp table is a huge pain.

Comment: Maybe you can achieve this using a procedure with a cursor like described here : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cursors.html. And you can get a complete list of your tables using this query to define the correct cursor : 
select * from information_schema.tables 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA NOT IN ('sys', 'mysql', 'performance_schema', 'information_schema')